# Tips for designing a serialization file format that will permit easy merging

Tags: serialization, merge, file-format, collaboration

Say I'm building a UML modeling tool.  There's some hierarchical organization to the data, and model elements need to be able to refer to others.  I need some way to save model files to disk.  If multiple people might be working on the files simultaneously, the time will come to merge these model files.  Also, it would be nice to compare two revisions in source control and see what has changed.  This seems like it would be a common problem across many domains

For this to work well using existing difference and merge tools, the file format should be text, separated onto multiple lines.

What are some existing serialization formats that do a good job (or poor job) addressing such problems?  Or, if designing a custom file format, what are some tips / guidelines / pitfalls?

Bonus question: Any additional guidance if I want to eventually split the model up into multiple files, each separately source controlled?

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem long ago for octave/matlab, now I need something for C#.
The task was to merge two octave-structs to one. I found no merge tool and no fitting serializer, so I had to think about something.

**The most important concept decision was to split the struct-tree into lines with the complete path and the content of the leave.**

The basic Idea was

1. Serialize the Struct to Lines, where each line represents a basic Variable (Matrix, string, float,...)
2. An array or matrix of struct will have the index in the path.
3. concatenate the two resulting text files, sort the lines
4. detect collisions and do collision-handling (very easy, because the same Properties will be positioned directly unde each other after the line sorting)
5. do deserialize

Example:

```
>> s1
```

s1 =

scalar structure containing the fields:

```
b =

  2x2 struct array containing the fields:

    bruch

t = Textstring
f =  3.1416
s =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    a =  3
    b =  4
```

will be serialized to

```
root.b(1,1).bruch=txt2base('isfloat|[ [ 0, 4 ] ; [ 1, 0 ] ; ]');
root.b(1,2).bruch=txt2base('isfloat|[ [ 1, 6 ] ; [ 1, 0 ] ; ]');
root.b(2,1).bruch=txt2base('isfloat|[ [ 2, 7 ] ; [ 1, 0 ] ; ]');
root.b(2,2).bruch=txt2base('isfloat|[ [ 7 ] ; [ 1 ] ; ]');
root.f=txt2base('isfloat|[3.1416]');
root.s.a=txt2base('isfloat|[3]');
root.s.b=txt2base('isfloat|[4]');
root.t=txt2base('ischar|Textstring');
```

The advantage of this method is, that it is very easy to implement and it is human readable. First you have to write the two functions base2txt and txt2base, wich convert basic types to strings and back. Then you just go recursively through the tree and write for each struct property the path to the property (here seperated by ".") and the content to one line.

The big disadvantage is, that at least my implementation of this is very slow.

The answer to the second question: Is there already something like this out there? I dont know... but I searched for a while, so I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Some guidelines:

The format should be designed so that when only one thing has changed in a model, there is only one corresponding change in the file.  Some counterexamples:

- It's no good if the file format uses arbitrary reference IDs that change every time you edit and save the model.
- It's no good if array items are stored with their indices listed explicitly, since inserting items into the middle of an array will cause all the following indices to get shuffled down.  That will cause those items to show up in a 'diff' unnecessarily.

Regarding references: if IDs are created serially, then two people editing the same revision of the model could end up creating new elements with the same ID.  This will become a problem when merging.

Comment: Usage of UUIDs may be a good idea here. Not necessarily 128bit IDs, you can also use something like hash(username)+serial or like that.

Comment: I would also avoid fixed-length fields, and comma-separated lists (hell to merge).

Comment: @Dan - this isn't an answer, why didn't you just update question with this content?  As it is it looks like (form the index pages) someone's addressed your question.

Comment: @Rudu: I agree.  I don't have an answer... was hoping to get some suggestions.  I thought maybe this "not-an-answer" was a starting point.  I also intended to make this CW but couldn't find the checkbox.  Seems like the kind of question that could have multiple valid suggestions and perhaps no right answer.

Comment: @rene: custom mergetool is an interesting idea -- maybe expecting to be able to do a "content-insensitive" merge using generic tools (e.g., diff3) isn't realistic.

Comment: @Dan Perhaps there is no answer ;)  So you're looking to decide on a file format that helps with using a generic revision control system (GIT, SVN, etc?)

Comment: @Rudu: Right.  The current file format has some issues.  I have ideas for making it better, but this seems like it would be a common problem that other people would have run into before.  In any case, it isn't really a high priority, so I'll keep thinking about it and update here whatever I come up with.